# WCF net.tcp binding with certificate based message security but security mode turned off

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, tcp, certificate

I have a WCF service and a desktop client. I use net.tcp binding. I have my own authentication method, however I would like the messages to be encrypted. So I install the same certificate on both parties. My configuration follows:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
   <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
         <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="Root" findValue="myCertificateIssuer" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
      </clientCredentials>
   </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

...

```
<binding name="simpleTCP" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
  sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
  <security mode="None">
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
  </security>
</binding>
```

I have the same configuration on server as well. The solution is working, however I don't know whether it really encrypts the message. Am I right to think, that this configuration turns the default authentication off, but still encrypts the channel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elaboration on initial response**

If you want to encrypt the *channel*, use a binding something like this for *transport-level* encryption:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TestTcp">
      <security mode="Transport"> <!-- Channel -->
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

To encrypt the *messages*, use a binding something like this for *message-level* encryption:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TestTcp">
      <security mode="Message"> <!-- Message -->
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

You'll notice the node below `<security/>` can be `<message/>` or `<transport/>`, which should match your selected `mode`. The `clientCredentialType` set to `Certificate` uses your service cert to do the encryption.

> "[To encrypt the channel] with netTcpBinding, when using Windows authentication, the binding uses the service’s Windows token to provide message protection. When using non-Windows authentication such as certificate authentication, you have to configure a service certificate as service credentials. The binding uses the service certificate for message protection."
>
> "[To encrypt the message] when using Windows authentication, message security uses the service’s Windows token to provide message security. When using non-Windows authentication such as username, certificate, or issue token authentication, you have to configure a service certificate as service credentials. Message security uses the service certificate for message protection."
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx

Hopefully that covers all the bases and gets you encrypting your message or channel with that x.509 certificate.

Comment: PS you may like to prove it to yourself. Try out Message Analyzer: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226

Comment: So, you are saying it is not possible to turn off authentication but still encrypting the communication channel? I do not need and do not want to configure authentication, but I would like the channel to be encrypted using the specified certificate. Is that possible?

Comment: Quite the contrary, you can enable and disable just about everything in WCF. WCF is "secure by default", which in most cases means you don't have to do anything to have secure messaging. Just noticed I misunderstood you wanted to encrypt the Message in the OP and not the Channel, so I'm updating my answer to show both.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try these. +1 for the detailed description.